# what is the meaning of the following lines?

Tags: meaning

Please help me to know the meaning of thefollowing
"Now set the x value to anything but zero,LED should be on position"

Answer (score 1):

The instruction is telling you to set the value of the x variable, whatever it represents, to something other than '0'.  The next part is written poorly, but I believe it is saying the LED should be on, or lit.
It should probably say,

> LED should be in the 'ON' position

Because of the comma, it sounds like the LED should be on after you set the x value.